# LINQ conditional selection and formatting

Tags: c#, linq, select, format

I have a string of characters and I'm trying to set up a query that'll substitute a specific sequence of similar characters into a character count. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

agd69dnbd**555**bdggjykbcx**555555**bbb

In this case, I'm trying to isolate and count ONLY the occurrences of the number 5, so my output should read:

agd69dnbd**3**bdggjykbcx**6**bbb

My current code is the following, where GroupAdjacentBy is a function that groups and counts the character occurrences as above.

```
var res = text
.GroupAdjacentBy((l, r) => l == r)
.Select(x => new { n = x.First(), c = x.Count()})
.ToArray();
```

The problem is that the above function groups and counts EVERY SINGLE character in my string, not the just the one character I'm after. Is there a way to conditionally perform that operation on ONLY the character I need counted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is a better tool for this job than LINQ.

Have a look at this:

```
string input = "agd69dnbd555bdggjykbcx555555bbb";

string pattern = @"5+"; // Match 1 or more adjacent 5 character

string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, match => match.Length.ToString());

// output = agd69dnbd3bdggjykbcx6bbb
```

Not sure if your intending to replace every 5 character, or just when there is more than one adjacent 5.

If it's the latter, just change your pattern to:

```
string pattern = @"5{2,}"; // Match 2 or more adjacent 5's
```

Comment: What if I were doing the same, but with arbitrary patterns? I'll illustrate my question with an example: agd69dnbd555bdggjykbcx555555bbb. The query would substitute the similar patterns it finds with a string of my choice, ex. "OK". In this case, it would substitute all occurrences of "bd" and "555" with "OK", resulting in agd69dnOKOKOKggjykbcxOKOKbbb

Comment: @user2729463 its difficult to provide a concrete answer for an "arbitrary" pattern, as that could vary immensely. All I would say is that Regex is *very* flexible for pattern matching in strings, so just build your pattern accordingly. This is a good resource: https://regexr.com/. To give an answer to your second example, the pattern would be simply `bd`, and you could replace the lambda in `Regex.Replace` with either the string `"OK"`, or `match => "OK"`.

Comment: Right now, I'm using thiis code:            

                 var tmp = lines
                .GroupBy(g => g)
                .Where(x => x.Count() > 1 && x.Key.Length > 1)
                .Select(s => new { Key = s.Key, Count = s.Count()})
                .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Count);

But I have to iterate through every resulting item in order to replace the repetitions. It's quite machine heavy if the original text is very long. I saw that LINQ statements are extremely fast. Can I adapt it to do what I need?

Comment: @user2729463 I really wouldn't be trying to use LINQ for string pattern matching; this is what Regex is designed for. As for LINQ being really fast, it depends how you use it; each method call you have done will be causing at least 1 further iteration, so by the time you have done `GroupBy`, `Where`, `Select`, `ToDictionary`, you have iterated over the collection 4 times, not to mention the 2 nested calls to `Count`, so iterating over all the resulting objects again isn't really an issue.

Comment: So how would you use Regex to do all that grouping and substituting?

Comment: @user2729463 a group is defined as a pattern e.g. `5+` or `bd` or anything else you need to find. Substituting is done either by inserting a simple string at each occurrence or providing a function that projects each match to a new string.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer was already given by Johnathan Barclay. But just for the case that you need something similar by using Linq and to show an alternative solution:

```
var charToCombine = '5';
var res = text
    .GroupAdjacentBy((l, r) => l == r )
    .SelectMany(x => x.Count() > 1 && x.First() == charToCombine ? x.Count().ToString() : x)
    .ToArray();
```